# Mineral spirits not drying on unfinished hardwood floor (12 hours later)

Tags: flooring, finishing, hardwood, sanding

I'm looking for suggestions on how to dry down or remove excess mineral spirits from our unfinished hardwood floor.

We installed new, unfinished hardwood flooring (yellow birch), sanded it and then wiped it down with mineral spirits. I think the mineral spirits were poured directly on the floor because now, 12 hours later, there are still areas that don't look completely dry. We're planning to use Zar Ultra Max Waterborne Oil Modified Poly to finish the floors. I tried wiping them down with a clean cloth but that didn't do much. Would sanding those areas lightly do the trick?

Comment: Since it soaked into the wood, I would suggest more like a week.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, sanding will not do any good. Warm air is likely the only thing that will eventually evaporate the excess, which probably soaked deeply into the wood if it was poured onto it. You are supposed to put it on the cleaning rag, not directly onto the surface, for this very reason. You can usually rent the kind of blowers used to dry out flooded areas. If not, get some duct tape, a hair dryer and a pole lamp or a chair and duct tape the hair dryer to the pole/chair so that it is pointing down at about a 45 degree angle (not straight down or you may burn out the dryer).